# display excel file content in table after file uploading on same page in struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to display excel file content in table format, after user upload excel file,
on the same page below file upload form in next div,, will it possible or what can i use for this to achive , with ajax, or

Answer (score 0):

There are quite many ways to achieve this and one of the most easy and flexible way is to use Apache POI.API is capable enough to read and write MS Excel docs.

Foe details refer the official POI site.

- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Another solution is to use ZK spreadsheet which is quite easy to use.

- [Zkspreadsheet](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkspreadsheet).

if its also possible you just load the excel document itself in a frame, iFrame or a popup Most browsers should handle that if Excel is installed on the user's machine.

Comment: @HimmatGadkari: if this solved the problem mark the answer as accepted so that it can help some other with similar issue